# DataFrame parallel vector calculations (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working on a trading backtester, I give it an initial capital, an history price dataframe, and randomly generated signals for entries and exits stored into the dataframe.

```
  | price | signal | entry | exit | shares | profit | capital
0      22        0     nan    nan        0        0      1000
1      24        1      24    nan    41,66        0      1000
2      22        1     nan    nan        0        0      1000
3      22        0     nan     22        0   -83,33    916,67
4      24        1      24    nan    41,66        0    916,67
```

When `['signal']` turns from 0 to 1 `['entry']` stores the entry price and `['shares']` stores: `['capital']/['entry price']`

When `['signal']` turns from 1 to 0 `['exit']` stores the exit price, `['profit']` stores: `(['exit']-['entry']) * ['shares'])` and `['capital']` stores the cumulative profit + the previous value `['capital'] + ['profit'].cumsum()`
So in this case:

```
entry = 24, 
shares = 24/1000 = 41.., 
exit = 22
profit = (22-24)*41 = -83
capital = 1000+(-83)
```

All of this operations are made by pandas vectorization because according to this article (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06) vectorization is much faster than for loops (especially with huge dataframe) so I absolutely need to avoid them.
Now, the calculations are written sequantially by the pandas `loc` vectorization method, but THE PROBLEM is:
the shares calculation comes before the capital calculation, so the shares calculation takes in consideration only the "initial" capital values, without considering the updated capital value, in fact if you LOOK AT THE DATAFRAME at the last row the shares are `1000/24=41,66`, when instead should be `916/24=38`.
I can fix it without loops?
PART OF THE CODE:

```
   # ENTRY/EXIT CONDITIONS
buy = ((data['signal'].shift(1) != 1) & (data['signal'] == 1))
buyclose = ((data['signal'].shift(1) == 1) & (data['signal'] != 1))

   # ENTRY PRICE 
data['entry'].loc[buy] = data['price'].shift(-1) 

   # SHARES 
data['shares'].loc[buy] = (data['capital'].loc[buy].values / data['entry'].loc[buy].values)

   # EXIT PRICE 
data['exit'].loc[buyclose] = data['price'].shift(-1) 

   # PROFIT 
data['profit'].loc[buyclose] = (data['exit'].loc[buyclose].values - data['entry'].loc[buy].values) * data['shares'].loc[buy].values

   # CAPITAL
data['capital'] = data['capital'].values + data['profit'].cumsum().values
```

EDIT FULL CODE:

```
from tvDatafeed import TvDatafeed, Interval
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

capital = 1000
leverage = 1
spread = 0.03

###  DATA  ###
data = TvDatafeed().get_hist(symbol='OIL_CRUDE',exchange='CAPITALCOM',interval=Interval.in_30_minute,n_bars=5000)
data = data.drop(['symbol','close','volume'], axis=1)
data = data.rename_axis('date').reset_index() 
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], unit='D')#.dt.date
data = data.rename_axis('index').reset_index() 

data['position'] = np.random.randint(3, size=len(data)) - 1
data.loc[0, 'position'] = 0 ### PROVVISORIO

new_entry = pd.DataFrame()
data['entry'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['entry date'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['exit'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['exit date'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['shares'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['profit'] = np.zeros((len(data)), int)
data['capital'] = np.full((len(data)), capital)


###  FIX LAST BUY/SELL  ###
index = 1
if data['position'].iloc[-1] != 0:
   fix = data['position'] != data['position'].iloc[-1]
   index = len(data.loc[fix[fix].index[-1]:])-1
        
### CONDITIONS ###  
nlast = (data['index'] < data['index'].iloc[-index]) #EXCLUDE LAST ENTRY
buy = ((data['position'].shift(1) != 1) & (data['position'] == 1) & (nlast))
sell = ((data['position'].shift(1) != -1) & (data['position'] == -1) & (nlast))
buyclose = ((data['position'].shift(1) == 1) & (data['position'] != 1))
sellclose = ((data['position'].shift(1) == -1) & (data['position'] != -1))

#####  ENTRIES  #####
   # ENTRY PRICE 
data['entry'].loc[buy] = data['open'].shift(-1) + spread
data['entry'].loc[sell] = data['open'].shift(-1) - spread 

#####   EXITS   #####
   # EXIT PRICE 
data['exit'].loc[buyclose] = data['open'].shift(-1) 
data['exit'].loc[sellclose] = data['open'].shift(-1)
data.loc[0, 'exit'] = 0 

##### CALCULATIONS #####
   # SHARES 
data['shares'].loc[buy] = (data['capital'].loc[buy].values / data['entry'].loc[buy].values) * leverage 
data['shares'].loc[sell] = (data['capital'].loc[sell].values / data['entry'].loc[sell].values) * leverage

   # PROFIT 
data['profit'].loc[buyclose] = (data['exit'].loc[buyclose].values - data['entry'].loc[buy].values) * data['shares'].loc[buy].values
data['profit'].loc[sellclose] = (data['entry'].loc[sell].values - data['exit'].loc[sellclose].values) * data['shares'].loc[sell].values

   # CAPITAL                                                                                                                                  
data['capital'] = data['capital'].values + data['profit'].cumsum().values 

print(data)
```

Comment: Hi, when I run your code, the "profit" line raises an exception: `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value`.

Comment: @Laurent I provided the full code in edit.